# Check database exists causes login request failed .why?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a method

```
public static bool CheckDatabaseExists()
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {               
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

When called it's all good but then when I go and execute a script from c# to create the tables I get

> > System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled
> >
> > HResult=-2146232060
> >
> > Message=Cannot open database "MyDatabase" requested by the login. The login failed.

This happens when I try to open the connection again

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    using (var command = new SqlCommand())
    {
        command.Connection = connection;
        connection.Open()
    }
}
etc....
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like the connection string you use in the CheckDatabaseExists is different to the one you use in your second connection. you do build the connection string in the same or different location?

Comment: @MPatel Connection string is the same that was a type of myne

Comment: Could you show us a stack trace of that exception?

Comment: if you use Windows Authentication, try adding Trusted_Connection=True;to you connection strng if you haven't already. I faced a similar issue today and that fixed it for me.